# What is the Chronological Order of the Sword Art Online Games?

Tags: sword-art-online-series

After seeing a lot Sword Art Online games in different platforms and orders compared to the anime, I wonder what Chronological Order they are.

The only thing that I know is that the Anime and Games split during

> The fight with Heathcliff

In a PSP Japan Exclusive game, but that's all.

Comment: Er...the split happens at the beginning of the game series.

Comment: As mentioned, I already know that. But because the order of the Full Dive Games (SAO, ALO, GGO, PA) does not matches the the games (example: Alice and Eugeo appear on GGO/Fatal Bullet where that does not makes sense in the Anime/Manga) I'm 100% sure that they have a different order.

Comment: Sinon is also in Hollow Fragment.  They're playing fast and loose with how things go.  Pretty sure the order is exactly the same, just moving forward with the story differently from the anime.

Comment: I would really like some evidence about "the order is exactly the same". What in game events confirm this?